# chrome is blocking insecure content from a secure script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a javascript_include_tag in a rails view, and chrome is throwing this warning:

```
[blocked] The page at https://..... ran insecure content from http://...index.js.
```

and none of the scripts load. But if you look in the html source, the script is included as https://

is this a chrome bug? what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a script included by a gem.

Make sure

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

is enabled in `config/application.rb`